# ASP.NET MVC3 and right opinionated client side software development model?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, dojo, client-side, google-closure

I am currently evaluating how to create and maintain MVC3 web applications that have a level of client side richness we've never attempted before. I realize this will require a much more thought out usage of javascript.

This lead to me starting research on Dojo and Closure. Of course the amount of information (especially in context with various versions) is just overwhelming on this.

Does anyone have any good sources of guidance on working with tools such as these in the context of MVC2+ style applications? Such as which mesh well, and which have the highest barriers, personal success or failure stories and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting, because I think Microsoft is leaning heavily toward wanting MVC users to use jQuery in their projects. jQuery is the only JavaScript framework included by default in the MVC project at creation. They are also actively developing plugins to use in MVC projects. Now I am not saying you should use jQuery for these reasons, but it is hard to ignore how much effort MS is putting towards jQuery and making it a large part of the MVC workflow.

Comment: The thing jQuery seems to be lacking is the Provides/Requires model. Unless this is in it, or in some plugin that i'm just not aware of.

Comment: BTW jQuery is one of the most powerful JavaScript Frameworks out there. I don't believe on any big disvantage about using it regarding Dojo.

Comment: @Eli yes, if there's a relevant tag for that feel free to swap that with one of the tags.

Comment: Have you considered that you aren't going to find all the features you want and may need to resort to using microframworks to fill in the gaps? http://microjs.com/

Comment: I most definitely haven't ruled out anything, I only mentioned Dojo and Closure for those being what I am aware of that have that support.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery all the way is the only way. MVC 3 libraries use it behind the scenes anyways now. Whats the issue with simply including the scripts as opposed to relying on the dogo.requires() ?

With jQuery - simple includes on your layout pages are all you need most of the time. There is some faultiness when you want validation to occur on an ajax loaded partial view in which you need to 'tell' jQuery about the new content to validate, but besides that its quite solid.

Comment: Sometimes sure but I don't think so when it comes to jQuery. With a basic dev policy in place and a standard place to put them, managing jQuery versions is trivial, no matter the size of the project. Don't mix versions and reference from one place and cache the version on the client. If it's more complex than that, reconsider the policy/central location and reference. Now - other library dependency management can get more difficult - but we've never had a huge issue with .net assemblies/jQuery no matter the size of the project I've worked on once versioning policies are defined.

Comment: And how much client side development was done on those projects by hand? Because I'm really feeling that elaborate work really needs to be built around the concept of package management. Unfortunately it seems like all of the JS tools are either built on Node.js and NPN and none use Nuget I saw. However it seems like relying on JavaScript files built around Asynchronous Module Definition http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition seems like the solution for maintaining a complex project.

Comment: Lots of client side functionality - animation, effects, ui elements - all contained specifically to jQuery core and ui that makes up 95% or everything. We use purr on occasion for confirmations, which is just another single library in scripts referenced from a layout. On occasion we use the telerik mvc extensions which contain their own script management (somewhat) and thats it.I like nuget, but personally wouldn't use it for jQuery ui as I prefer the custom build of ui for components we use and themeroller. I think I'm just saying don't let the lack of two methods kill it : )

Comment: @Chris Marisic, I think the other people are saying that you really should know exactly *why* you need automated script dependency management in your project, because it limits your choices.  If you don't absolutely need it, you have a much wider choice of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled onto this question: not sure whether you're still interested in it.

There are several internal initiatives inside Dojo to build an MVC module and low-level "binding" functionalities into Dojo, and use automatic binding as the "glue" between the model object and the view (or widgets inside the view).

dojox.mvc is where most of this work is currently residing.

I have a small implementation of automatic binding (similar to WPF so you can actually do MVVM with Dojo) intended as a plumbing layer in Dojo.  There is a small proof-of-concept test page here: http://www.mingleplace.com/test/bindingtest.html

So, the short answer is that MVC is actively being developed/pursued in Dojo, and experimental packages are already available.  However, as far as when the actual API will be formalized into Dojo, you probably have to wait till 2.0...

Comment: That sounds more like a competitor to KnockoutJS than where my question is going.

Comment: @Chris Marisic, well you did ask about MVC and Dojo...  What I wrote just said that Dojo does have built-in support of MVCin the dojox.mvc package (which you can use), and there are other things cooking internally for future versions as well.  So I don't see why it is irrelevant to your question.